# ng-token-auth for all subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm working on a Rails app with an Angular front end and we're using ng-token-auth and devise_token_auth for authentication.

We've got it working pretty well, but need to persist the session across different subdomains (`www.app.com`, `api.app.com`, `test.app.com`, for example).

I'm trying to set the cookieOps object:

```
$authProvider.configure({
    apiUrl: '',
    cookieOps: {
      domain: '*.app.com'
    }
});
```

But this seems to have no effect. Anybody accomplished this?

Answer (score 0):

We are using ng-token-auth over different subdomains. Try and replace cookieOps: { domain: 'app.com' } . It should work (remove the *. prefix)